# Adding V-LATE extension to ArcMap 10.3 running on Windows 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, installation, extensions, windows-10

I failed to add the V-late extension to ArcMap 10.3 running on Windows 10.
After trying to add the ***V_LATE_2beta_argis10.tlb*** in the customise mode with administration rights, I get the Message box "no new objects added".

Is there any known bug?

Comment: Does this .tlb have an associated .dll?

Comment: Yes it does. I didn't mention it but the .dll is located in the same folder like it should.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to include a link to the software distribution site, preferably one that indicates that the extension is designed to function with 10.3.x and works with Windows 10.

Comment: Here's the [location](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=36f9728a895e4f5386bdec68be6d08ac) which says it works only on 10.0 and 10.1. It looks like there's going to be a new one, [ZonalMetrics](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/euc15/papers/euc_11.pdf), on ArcGIS Online soon. Contact the author?

Comment: @mkennedy, sounds like you have an answer, extension not compatible with software version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V-LATE runs in ArcGIS 10.x (incl. 10.3.1) and also in different Windows versions (tested until version 8.1, Windows 10 not confirmed yet). 
Sometimes the relevant files (*tlb and *dll) are blocked by Windows after the download:

- Download and unzip the file in a folder that does not have dashes in the name (specify a different location to unzip instead of accepting the default).
- Right click on the V_LATE_2beta_argis10.dll files, go to "Properties", select the unblock button (if available) & hit apply (sometimes Windows is blocking these files automatically due to security reasons). Repeat the procedure also for the *.tlb file, which is actually the file you then have to load in ArcMap.
- Check again if the files are now unblocked (if the "Unblock" button is still present, check your write-permission for the folder structure
- move the files maybe to another drive/folder) Open ArcMap in administrator mode (right mouse-click, "run as administrator") and add the *.tlb file in ArcMap.

However, there is some feedback from different users that it is sometimes still not working on specific systems - I assume it's due to security settings in the newer Windows versions, but I am not sure. I could not replicate the issue on my computers.

ZonalMetrics will be a different software with different functionalities, i.e. no replacement of V-Late

Answer (score 2):

I found at least one download site for V-LATE, Vector-based Landscape Analysis Tools 2.0 [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=36f9728a895e4f5386bdec68be6d08ac) on ArcGIS.com. The author states that it works on ArcGIS for Desktop 10.0 and 10.1 only. There's also a link to a version that runs on ArcGIS Desktop 9.

There were a lot of changes at 10.2, including some major changes in ArcObjects. That may be way it won't run at later versions.

Checking on the person who posted V-LATE 2.0, Dirk Tiede, led me to a [presentation](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/euc15/papers/euc_11.pdf) (4.1 MB) at the 2015 Esri Education User Conference on ZonalMetrics. It looks like it has the same functionality, and is a python toolbox. The authors, Joanna Adamczyk and Dirk Tiede, say that it will be posted on ArcGIS Online soon. The presentation has an email for Dr Tiede so you could try contacting him for more information.